# Dynamically set the object type to dwg imported object in revit

Tags: c#, 3dsmax, revit-api, revit

I have a wall in **3D Studio Max**. I know that the object is wall but max don't know it, max only know that it is an object. While in **Revit** tool, it is defined that it is roof or wall or door etc.

Now in my case I want to export my max object(wall) into revit and I can export dwg in revit. If i export the dwg through max for revit then, I want that it dynamically pick the object type(that it is wall, roof or any else object). With plugin or without plugin or with custom script is this possible? It seems that there is no built-in support, so it there any workaround available?

Answer (score 0):

you can try IFC format instead DWG

Comment: But (i guess) I can export IFC format from max. Isn't?

Comment: is there any way available to make IFC file from Max?

Comment: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/3ds-max-ideas/ifc-exporter-updated-to-include-import-and-export/idc-p/7588348/highlight/true#M4171

Comment: But there is no guide available yet that teach us how to make IFC from max! did you read the thread?

Answer (score 0):

Search the web for [3ds max revit export](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=3ds+max+revit+export). For instance, I see the following hits:

- [How to Import 3Ds in Revit](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-import-3ds-in-revit)
- [how to import a 3Ds Max file to revit](https://youtu.be/Plic498h7aM)

However, after reading the first post, it appears that there is little support for automatically categorising BIM objects in the manner you wish.

I hope you can find some deeper explanations with better suggestions for automating this.

Comment: Well i have already checked both links..i want to set the type automatically.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no built-in functionality to achieve this. To do so, you could add some intelligence of your own. E.g., tag the 3DS objects in some way that can be read and recognised by a Revit add-in that post-processes the model to categorise elements appropriately.